# Nothing changes on a page when i change css "display" property of an element via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simle application which is intended to filter list(displays items that matches and hides the rest)

There is function which is triggered by 'input' event on `<input>` element. It changes the "display" attribute for `<li>` element. And finally it adds proper attribute value(block or none) to each `<li>`. However i do not see any changes on a page.

Here is a code:

```
function filterInput(e) {
   //value from <input> element
   let keyValue = e.target.value;
   //all items from list
   let listOfTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.list-group-item');
   listOfTasks.forEach(function (task) {
      const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
      if(~item.indexOf(keyValue)){
         task.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
         task.style.display = 'none';
      }
   });
}
```

Here is screenshot of elements before event:

[image: elements before event]

Here is screenshot of elements after event:

[image: elements after event]

And on the page nothing changes:

[image: the list itself]

Comment: Why are you using bitwise not? And are you absolutely sure the property is being set? Last but not least, please don't post links. Embed the images instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that CSS for ".list-group-item" has "display: block !important", which takes priority over inline styling. Because the inline styling is assigned, but doesn't take effect...

Comment: Likely a good guess, but should really be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was in ".d-flex" class